# Why this SVG radial progress (circular percentage) doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Based on [this tutorial on radial progress](https://codepen.io/xgad/post/svg-radial-progress-meters) (that we call circular percentage) we tried to create some SVG drawings for 0, 20, 40, 60, 80 and 100 percent.

These are the steps that we took for each SVG:

1. Creating two `<circle>` elements inside an `<svg>` tag
2. Calculating `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` based on the percentage, radius and circumference such that the sum of `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` should be equal to circumference

[Here in this sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZwpNm) you can see SVG drawings for 0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100 percent of progress.

```css
.circularPercentage {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<svg class="circularPercentage" fill="none" width="150" height="150" percent="0">
    <circle class="background" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" cx="75" cy="75" stroke-width="15" r="67.5"></circle>
    <circle class="percentage" fill="none" cx="75" cy="75" stroke="#FF0000" stroke-width="15" r="67.5" stroke-dasharray="424.11500823462205" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>

<svg class="circularPercentage" fill="none" width="150" height="150" percent="20">
    <circle class="background" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" cx="75" cy="75" stroke-width="15" r="67.5"></circle>
    <circle class="percentage" fill="none" cx="75" cy="75" stroke="#FF6600" stroke-width="15" r="67.5" stroke-dasharray="84.82300164692441" stroke-dashoffset="339.29200658769764"></circle>
</svg>

<svg class="circularPercentage" fill="none" width="150" height="150" percent="40">
    <circle class="background" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" cx="75" cy="75" stroke-width="15" r="67.5"></circle>
    <circle class="percentage" fill="none" cx="75" cy="75" stroke="#FFCC00" stroke-width="15" r="67.5" stroke-dasharray="169.64600329384882" stroke-dashoffset="254.46900494077323"></circle>
</svg>

<svg class="circularPercentage" fill="none" width="150" height="150" percent="60">
    <circle class="background" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" cx="75" cy="75" stroke-width="15" r="67.5"></circle>
    <circle class="percentage" fill="none" cx="75" cy="75" stroke="#CBFF00" stroke-width="15" r="67.5" stroke-dasharray="254.46900494077323" stroke-dashoffset="169.64600329384882"></circle>
</svg>

<svg class="circularPercentage" fill="none" width="150" height="150" percent="80">
    <circle class="background" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" cx="75" cy="75" stroke-width="15" r="67.5"></circle>
    <circle class="percentage" fill="none" cx="75" cy="75" stroke="#65FF00" stroke-width="15" r="67.5" stroke-dasharray="339.29200658769764" stroke-dashoffset="84.82300164692441"></circle>
</svg>

<svg class="circularPercentage" fill="none" width="150" height="150" percent="100">
    <circle class="background" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" cx="75" cy="75" stroke-width="15" r="67.5"></circle>
    <circle class="percentage" fill="none" cx="75" cy="75" stroke="#00FF00" stroke-width="15" r="67.5" stroke-dasharray="424.11500823462205" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>
```

What do we miss that it doesn't work as expected for percentages other than 0 and 100?

Answer (score 2):

You're not understanding how stroke dash-array works. If you just size your dash-array correctly (to equal the perimeter length - 2*Pi*R) then you don't need an offset and you'll get something that (I think) you're expecting. Here is the first one, for example:

```css
.circularPercentage {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<svg class="circularPercentage" fill="none" width="150" height="150" percent="20">
    <circle class="background" fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" cx="75" cy="75" stroke-width="15" r="67.5"></circle>
    <circle class="percentage" fill="none" cx="75" cy="75" stroke="orange" stroke-width="15" r="67.5" stroke-dasharray="80 344.17" stroke-dashoffset="0"></circle>
</svg>
```